# increase video js height but not background

Tags: javascript, html, css, video.js

I have a video using video.js on a pc the video covers the whole screen (height & width) on mobile size its just a small hight and the black background covers the rest.

How do I change the actual size of the video to fill 100% of height of a mobile screen so the plain black background can't be seen?

Code I have tried is below.

```
  <div class="top">
        <video id="my-video" class="video-js" responsive="true" height="100%" object-fit="cover" autoplay="true" preload="true" responsive="true"
            loop="true" data-setup='{"fluid": true}' muted>
            <source  src="images/Untitled.mov" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="images/Untitled.mov" type="video/webm" />
        </video>
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/8.0.4/video.min.js"></script>
    </div>
```

```
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.video-js {
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -50;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -95px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data-setup='{"fluid": true}'` was removed and then filled the space I set

Answer (score 1):

```css
#my-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

This should be work. You may also want to remove the **height="100%"** and **responsive="true"** attributes from the video tag, as they may interfere with the CSS styles.

Comment: thanks, but this is still creating the same problem where the video stays the same size and a black background covers the rest